# Where to find latest API-version of Microsoft Azure ServiceBus REST API

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Trying to get messages of Azure Servicebus via Rest API;

```
https://<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<queue-name>/messages/head?api-version=??&timeout=60
```

I need to provide an api-version as request-parameter, otherwise results in 400 - bad request (*request is not supported for the supplied api-version ''*).
Found a very old one in documentation (**2015-01**), but expect that this version is not having lock-tokens in broker-property header and a newer version is..

Or otherwise how do I get a lock-token to delete a message that was retrieved in peek-lock mode?

Comment: Really stupid mistake, I was doing a GET-call instead of a POST-call to get messages..

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this?

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/{namespaceName}/topics/{topicName}?api-version=2021-11-01
```

[Azure Service bus API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/stable/topics/get?tabs=HTTP)

Comment: Unfortunately my connection-string has limited privileges (external party), so only able to receive/delete messages. Not able to do any management-related actions.
I found this documentation to get messages from servicebus in peek-lock modus;

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/peek-lock-message-non-destructive-read

But if I call this endpoint without api-version query-paramater its complaining about this missing api-version (unsupported api-version <empty>). Whenever I set api-version to 2015-01 it will return messages but without lock-token in broker-property header.

Comment: It looks like its not locking my received message when I call peek-lock read.
Because I expected a LockedUntilUtc and LockToken-property in broken-properties of response-header - according https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/message-headers-and-properties - but I dont have them..